# "Singular Perturbation" is not among tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Can I ask  MO to  define  a new  tag "Singular  perturbation". I did not find this  tag  among the tag  list.

Thank you

Comment: When you reach 1000 reputation, you may create tags yourself.  We find it best that someone have more experience before making changes.

Comment: @Gerald, I think you'll find this user reached 1000 some years ago, but has given most of it away in bounties.

Comment: I was tripped up.  His rep here (in Meta) is less than 1000.

Comment: To add one more minor correction to what @GeraldEdgar wrote, MO currently has privilege to create tags at [300 reputation points](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/create-tags). There are some sites where this privilege is set to 1000 reputation points,
on such example [is Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: @MartinSleziak  based on your helpful  comment  I  create  the  tag  I  need in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292048/canard-limit-cycle-for-certain-singularly-perturbed-system). Thank you.